# Using “Can I know the price?”

Tags: questions

Does it sounds odd to say “Can I know the price?”

Comment: The idiomatic way is, "How much does this cost?"

Comment: With your formulation you are really asking if the price is knowable and if you are capable of knowing it-  probably not what  you really want to know.

Comment: Or "Could you tell me how much this is, please?"

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Do read the FAQ here: https://english.stackexchange.com/help/asking

Comment: It will sound more natural if it comes after a statement of things that you know, e.g. looking at cheeses in the dairy case at a deli. That blue one over there looks good. Can I know the price?  However, a more idiomatic expression would be *How much is it?*

Comment: You are on the wrong site! As you should have read in the Tour, "EL&U SE is a question and answer site for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts". Perhaps your question will fit [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com), but check carefully before posting.

Comment: It would sound odd to me in some contexts, but quite normal to me in other contexts. It depends on the situation.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it sounds odd to me. The normal way would be

> What is the price?

Comment: I agree.  If I heard that (*May/Can I know...*) I'd assume the speaker was not a native English speaker.

Answer (score -1):

**Can you use 'can' or must you use 'may'?**  [Meriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/when-to-use-can-and-may)

Yes, you can use can and it is not odd sounding to my sense:  **Can i know the price?**

But ...

> In reality, can likely has more use in the “permission” sense than is
>   recorded, as it is more informal and so shows up in speech more
>   frequently than may does. May is the more formal word, and if you are
>   at all concerned about being tut-tutted, a safe choice. Can is now the
>   verb of choice for ability, and both can and may are still used in the
>   "possibility" sense. You may use can if you wish, and you can use may
>   if it makes you feel better.

Comment: Saying 'May I know the price' sounds classy. It is a phrase I will start using more often.